# Does Qt have an analog of gsl::span?

Tags: c++, qt

Does Qt have an implementation of `span`? C++ Core Guidelines recommend the use of `gsl::span` to wrap a pointer and a length when they designate a non-owned sequence of elements of the pointer's type.

For the read-only case for `QChar`, there is `QStringView`. Does an analog of `QStringView` exist for bytes in Qt? What about writable analogs of these?

Comment: I haven't used `gsl::span` personally but from what I can see it appears functionally similar to [`boost::asio::mutable_buffer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/mutable_buffer.html)(or its [`const alternative`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/const_buffer.html)) -- assuming a `boost` based solution is acceptable.

Comment: `QLatin1String` ? According qt it's a wrapper for a "US-ASCII/Latin-1 encoded string literal", but it looks like it should work for any bytes range. Not sure where the encoding requirement comes from and the requirement that it wraps a "string literal".

Comment: Using Boost isn't a solution using idiomatic Qt or Qt without other dependencies. If the answer turns out to be the Qt can't do this and another library is needed, GSL or just the `span` part of GSL is a smaller dependency to add than Boost. As for `QLatin1String`, I don't see what it solves for the purspose of representing a non-owned span of bytes that `QByteArray` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a QByteArray for that. You just need to construct it with `QByteArray::setRawData` on an existing QByteArray or `QByteArray::fromRawData` to create a new one like so:

```
std::vector<char> myvec{'t','e','s','t'};
QByteArray slice = QByteArray::fromRawData((const char*)myvec.data(),myvec.size());
```

This does not copy the data and it does not destroy it when the QByteArray is destroyed.

But be aware that this is copy-on-write, so modifying the original sequence throught the QByteArray will not be possible.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue. As you say, `QByteArray` is COW, which means if you get call `.data()` on a non-const object, you'll get allocation. The same goes for `operator[]`. So unless you make it a `const QByteArray`, there's no way to access the data without provoking allocation.

Comment: Thank you. Looks like `QByteArray::fromRawData` works for wrapping a pointer and length and extracting them again for read-only purposes. Compared to `span`, though, it seems that there aren't methods for creating further non-owning read-only subspans. E.g. `right()` appears to copy the data.